# Best practice to find whether a for loop have been completed

Tags: c, logic

If I have a function `f1` that scans things in a `for` loop:

```
// f1:

for(i=0;i<7;i++) {
   //If conditions match Do things
   break;
}
```

What is the recommended way to keep a flag that tracks whether the scanning has been completed entirely? If I use a flag like this:

```
if(i==6) {
  flag=1;
}
```

Should I keep the flag `extern`/`global`, or should I wrap it in to some function?

What is the best way to allow it to be checked as to whether the for loop has been completely run through once?

Comment: Just check if i==7 after for loop.

Comment: @moeCake that's a simple solution but be careful: you've written the number `7` twice, which means someone may change one without the other, an easy source of bugs.

Comment: The fact that you're asking the question means that you are looking at this the wrong way. A loop is a mechanism that performs a task. When control exits the loop, the task is done. If the loop can finish its task early, great, but that's it's business. If you need to know whether the loop exited early then maybe the loop *should not* have exited early *because its work was not done*.

Comment: Think about it this way: suppose the loop was in a function of its own. **Does the caller of the function need to know that the function contains a loop that might exit early**?  How would you write such a function?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a matter of personal style, or the style prescribed by the coning standards of your company, university, class, whatever. Having said that, I personally prefer the following "pattern" when I want to break out of a loop when a certain condition is met (or if the entire loop completed without ever meeting that condition):

```
int found = 0;

for (int i = 0; !found && i < max; i++)
{
    if ( // condition I want )
    {
        found = 1;
    }
}

if (found)
    // do something
else
    // condition was never met
```

I personally don't like using `break` statements in loops because (similar to `goto`) you want to avoid introducing sudden breaks from the normal flow of execution. This makes code more readable and maintainable. But this is just an opinion, so you are free to make up your mind in this regard.

Comment: Hm, totally a style preference. To me, personally, your code looks a lot more complicated than one with goto.

Comment: @VladLazarenko to each his own...

Answer (score 2):

For a `for` loop, you can check to see if all loops have completed by checking if the terminating condition has been reached. If the terminating condition has not yet been reached, then there must have been a jump out of the loop early (either with `break` or `goto`).

This tactic works perfectly so long as your loop body does not force the terminating condition to be reached as a way to leave the loop early.

So long as you are making a local decision about what to do, there is no need for anything other than local variables. Using global variables to store flags is only useful for flags that intend to affect global behavior.